# Перманентная проблема с подключением и поиском в MongoDB 3.0, NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Версия NodeJs = 8.9.4;

Версия MongoDB-server  = 3.0;

Версия модуля  = 3.0;

Есть такой код подключения и поиска в БД, который `периодически` не работает :

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongodb = new mongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
var baza = "test";
var collectionName= "goods";

function findInDb(data, callback){
        // открываю подключение к БД
        console.log("*****до mongodb.connect******");
            mongodb.connect((err, client)=>{
                if (err) throw err;
                var db = client.db("goods");
                //подключаюсь к коллекции
                console.log("*****до db.collection******");
                db.collection(collectionName,(err, collection) =>{
                    if (err) throw err;
                    //запускаю поиск документов соответствующих критерию поиска
                    console.log("*****до collection.find******");
                    console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data));;
                    collection.find(data, {projection:{id:1}}).sort(sortValue).skip(skip).limit(limit).toArray((err, result)=>{
                        if (err) throw err;
                        //теперь необходимо узнать кол-во документов соответствующих критерию поиска (для пагинации)
                        console.log("*****до collection.count******")
                        collection.count(data,(err, count) =>{
                            if (err) throw err;
                            var f ={};
                            f.result = result;
                            f.count = count;
                            client.close();
                            console.log("*****client.close()******")
                            return callback(f);
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
}
```

Когда все норм консоль выдает следующее (как и ожидается):

```
    до mongodb.connect
    до db.collection
    до collection.find
    data: {"$and":[{"visible":true},{"id":{"$in":[16]}}]}
    до collection.count
    Result:  [id: 16]
    Count: 1
    client.close();
```

а когда работать не хочет - выбрасывает исключение и еще какие-то непонятные мне надписи):

```
до mongodb.connect
the options [socketOptions] is not supported
the options [read_preference_tags] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [server_options] is not supported
the options [db_options] is not supported
the options [rs_options] is not supported
the options [mongos_options] is not supported
до db.collection
до collection.find
data: {"$and":[{"visible":true},{"id":{"$in":[16]}}]}

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^
MongoError: Topology was destroyed
    at nextFunction (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:588:27)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:791:3)
    at fetchDocs (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:931:10)
    at toArray (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:957:3)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:409:22)
    at Cursor.toArray (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:917:10)
    at db.collection (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\myModules\findIndb.js:38:93)
    at Db.collection (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:445:21)
    at mongodb.connect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\myModules\findIndb.js:35:7)
    at args.push (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Back-end\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:405:72)
Program node .\app.js exited with code 1
```

Подскажите - в чем проблема?

P.S. После тестов определил, что проблема возникает, только если функцию запустить несколько раз подряд, например в цикле. Если запускать ее 1 раз и дожидаться выполнения, то все работает норм.

Comment: предпологаю,  что из-за асинхронности запросов подключения к mongo в цикле... Попробуйте вынести подключение за пределы функции и обернуть саму функцию в промисы...

Comment: @C.Raft Вы хотите сказать, что должно быть одно, постоянно открытое подключение, для любых запросов? Работая с модулем Mongodb 2.0 я привык, что для каждого запроса создается новое подключение. Да и все равно, что это за сообщение такое `is not supported`?)

Comment: Конечно.. а сообщение с ошибками, скорей всего, проистекает оттуда же...

Comment: @C.Raf.T, понятно. Я создал вопрос на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801348/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-mongodb-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8. Но на данный вопрос это не дает ответа. В модуле версии 2.0 эта же функция (немного измененная под нюансы версии) работает отлично. Как сделать так, чтобы и в версии 3.0 она работала так же?)

Comment: Скорее должно быть 1 открытое подключение для 1 запроса) Когда подключение открыто, от базы данные не вернулись, а вы уже кидаете новый запрос - вот и ошибка.
Вынесите запрос вообще в отдельную функцию, сделайте её асинхронной и вызывайте...

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка должна уйти, если параметры подключения к базе указывать в самом методе connect:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var baza = "test";
var collectionName= "goods";

function findInDb(data, callback){
    // открываю подключение к БД
    console.log("*****до mongodb.connect******");
    mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            var db = client.db("goods");
            ...
```