# Количество подключений к MongoDb. Правильность организации

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Добрый день! Есть функция, которая для каждого запроса к БД создает новое подключение. После выполнения запроса подключение закрывается.

Работая с модулем MongoDb версии 2.0 (NodeJs), у меня к этой функции вопросов не возникало. В процессе создания проекта (магазина) она работала отлично. 
После обновления модуля до версии 3.0 - начались проблемы. Ссылка на соответствующий вопрос: [Перманентная проблема с подключением и поиском в MongoDB 3.0, NodeJs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799102/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-mongodb-3-0-nodejs)
Код функции, естественно немного переделан, но суть осталась та же.

В комментариях посоветовали создать одно подключение для любых запросов. В связи с чем вот и возник у меня данный вопрос. Как лучше организовать код для работы с MongoDb: создать одно подключение для любых запросов (запросы могут быть одновременные, разного характера) или для каждого запроса создавать новое подключение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рамках одного приложения (не считая возможность кластеризации) соединение с базой устанавливается один раз, а переподключение происходит только в случае разрыва соединения.

Создание отдельного подключения к базе на каждый запрос неэффективно и затратно. Хоть я и допускаю возможность существования задач где постоянная поддержка соединения не требуется, но это частные случаи и должны быть рассмотрены индивидуально.