# Как сохранить импортированную информацию из MongoDB внутри всего проекта?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Мне нужно хранить инфу из базы данных внутри **всего** проекта (а не только внутри функции `MongoClient.connect`). Как это можно сделать?

Пробовал асинхронные функции - не помогло.

`global.oneRecord` вне `MongoClient.connect` возвращает пустой массив, а мне там нужны данные, чтобы можно было их экспортировать через module.exports в индексный файл.

Код:

```js
let fetchMyData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/info', function(err, db){
                            db.collection('dallaslockrecords').find({ids_name: 'Dallas Lock'}).toArray(function(err, recordings){
                                var recLength = recordings.length;
                                global.oneRecord.id = recordings[recLength - 1]._id;
                                console.log('global.oneRecord');
                                console.log(global.oneRecord);
                            });
                            db.close();
                        })
            });



fetchMyData.then(
                console.log(global.oneRecord),
                console.log('promise err')
            );
```

Comment: а разве Mongo.connect - хранит инфу из БД?

Comment: и вот еще - подумайте над этим - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801348/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-mongodb-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема?

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

;(async function main(){
    //Асинхронно законнектились
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    const db = client.db("someDB")
    const collection = db.collection("someCollection")

    //Получили результаты вне коннекта
    const results = await collection.find({}).toArray()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))

    client.close()
})()
```